# Dynamic Declaration of Cursor or Record

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, cursor, record

Can we dynamically declare a cursor or record?

```
CURSOR employee_id_cur
     IS
select * from <user entry table name>
```

Similar for the record.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following example:

```
DECLARE
TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
emp_cv EmpCurTyp;
emp_rec emp%ROWTYPE;
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
my_job VARCHAR2(15) := 'CLERK';
BEGIN
    sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE job = :j';
    OPEN emp_cv FOR sql_stmt USING my_job;
    LOOP
        FETCH emp_cv INTO emp_rec;
        EXIT WHEN emp_cv%NOTFOUND;
        -- process record section.....
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE emp_cv;
END;

/
```

Comment: In the meantime Oracle provides a shorcut, simply write `emp_cv SYS_REFCURSOR;` instead of `TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR; emp_cv EmpCurTyp;`